# UWP ParallaxView not working on Windows April 2018 Update

Tags: c#, uwp, parallax, uwp-xaml

The ParallaxView control in my UWP App was working fine with the code below. Since Windows April 2018 Update, it has stopped. I am using OS build 17134.112. Incidentally, this Control is also not working as expected in Microsoft XAML Controls Gallery app (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/xaml-controls-gallery/9msvh128x2zt). The background image does not move.

This is my XAML code, which is similar to the official example (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/motion/parallax):

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid x:Name="AllContentGrid" Background="Transparent" Margin="4,4,4,4" >
        <ParallaxView Source="{x:Bind MyEditBox}" VerticalShift="250">
            <Image x:Name="BackgroundImage" Source="ms-appx:///Assets//Images/ParallaxBackground.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </ParallaxView>

        <RichEditBox x:Name="MyEditBox" IsReadOnly="True" IsSpellCheckEnabled="False" IsTextPredictionEnabled="False"
                     RequiresPointer="Never" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" BorderThickness="0"
                     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" Foreground="Black" Padding="40,40,40,20" FontSize="16"
                     Style="{StaticResource MyRichEditBoxStyle}">
        </RichEditBox>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Thank you for reading/replying.

Comment: Thank you both (@RoguePlanetoid and @pstrjds). Glad I'm not the only one who faced this issue. Let's hope it gets fixed soon.

Comment: This seems to be working again after the August 14, 2018—KB4343909 (OS Build 17134.228) update :-)